# How to merge two arrays into one without iteration

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Currently if I do this:

```
$array1 = [27476, 29173, 24551, 21109, 29754, 19116, 25924, 27406, 26878, 20866, 32889, 25975];

$array2 = [25959, 26427, 26775, 24968, 24501, 27218, 27441, 27353, 25074, 27344, 26794, 25355];

$data = array_merge(
    array_merge_recursive(
        $array1, 
        $array2
    )
);
```

I get this:

```
    array3 = [
    0: 25959
    1: 26427
    2: 26775
    3: 24968
    4: 24501
    5: 27218
    6: 27441
    7: 27353
    8: 25074
    9: 27344
    10: 26794
    11: 25355
    12: 27476
    13: 29173
    14: 24551
    15: 21109
    16: 29754
    17: 19116
    18: 25924
    19: 27406
    20: 26878
    21: 20866
    22: 32889
    23: 25975 
    ];
```

Is it possible to merge it like the following?:

```
    array3 = [
    0 => [27476, 25959]
    1 => [29173, 26427]
    2 => [24551, 26775]
    .
    .
    .
    .
    ];
```

I wanted without iteration, its possible maybe using php7+ which I am not familiar.

Any help would be appricated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47421337/2943403

Comment: More important questions for me are: 1. Where are these input arrays coming from? Database? File? 2. Where is this data going that you need them to be repackaged?  Json? Database query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't understand **what** is the problem with iteration, but still:

```
$result = array_map(null, $array1, $array2);
```

Based on [`array_map` behaviour](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php#refsect1-function.array-map-examples) with `null` as first argument.

Comment: I guess like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54098206/merge-values-from-different-arrays-to-one-with-the-same-key/54098417#54098417